# "com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes" error on Jersey Rest

Tags: java, xml, rest

I know this questions been before on this site but I have taken advice from these pages and haven't been able resolve the problem yet. When trying to run a Rest Web Service using Jersey, I come across the following error message:-

***EXCEPTION***

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

***ROOT CAUSE***

```
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:491)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

After doing the reasearch, i have narowed it down to 3 problems:-

1. Errors within the web.xml.
2. No resources used within packaged project.
3. Problems with .jar files.

I have edited the web.xml as much as possible and have gotten nowhere with it. Below is the current web.xml file i am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>com.epware.jersey.book</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.epware.jersey.book.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I cannot locate any problems within the linked package. This is probably where the error is but i am struggling to find it myself. Again, the code for this is below.

```
// Will map the resource to the URL todos
@Path("/books")
public class BooksResource {

    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Context
    Request request;


    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public List<Book> getBooksBrowser() {
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
        books.addAll( BookDao.instance.getModel().values() );
        return books; 
    }

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
        books.addAll( BookDao.instance.getModel().values() );
        return books; 
    }

    @GET
    @Path("count")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getCount() {
        int count = BookDao.instance.getModel().size();
        return String.valueOf(count);
    }

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public void newBook(
            @FormParam("id") String id,
            @FormParam("title") String title,
            @FormParam("description") String description,
            @FormParam("authorFirst") String authorFirst,
            @FormParam("authorSecond") String authorSecond,
            @FormParam("publisher") String publisher,
            @FormParam("publishDate") String publishDate,
            @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse
    ) throws IOException {
        Book book = new Book(id,title,description,authorFirst,authorSecond,publisher,publishDate);
        BookDao.instance.getModel().put(id, book);
        System.out.println(BookDao.instance.getModel().toString());
        servletResponse.sendRedirect("../create_todo.html");
    }

    @Path("{book}")
    public BookResource getBook(
            @PathParam("book") String id) {
        return new BookResource(uriInfo, request, id);
    }

}
```

I am currently using Jersey jars version 1.18 as shown in the image below:-

External Link to Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6tpC.png

Any help is greatly appreciated a i am on limited time now to get this done.

Comment: What's the `BooksResource` qualified name?

Comment: com.epware.jersey.resources.BooksResource. There is another resource file in there called BookResource that isnt pathed but that shouldnt be accessible from the web service anyway.

Comment: Try use in `param-value` this package: `com.epware.jersey.resources`.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, package is actually `com.epware.jersey.book.resources`

Comment: Ok, so your config is ok. Check that your application deployed correctly and that your `WEB-INF/classes` folder actually contains your class with the proper folder path for the package. Do a full clean and rebuild, then try again. I can't see other problem =/

Comment: Clean and rebuild worked a charm. Now have a fully working REST Web Service. Thank you Bruno for your help. I'll remember next time to do this step before posting to here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in comments, your configuration is OK. However, apparently you changed the resource package.

Thus the classpath has not been updated. As in comments, a full clean and rebuild will update the classpath (compiled and resources) and worked.

Answer (score 0):

try this @Path(books).It Worked for me or should check

```
com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages
```

param value in web.xml. Your package is name is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue why this worked for me, but I had like 6 Jersey sample applications in one workspace and it was giving me the error in one of the applications. After moving that application to another Eclipse workspace and opened a new Eclipse window, the application worked.